# Control.ClientRectangle vs Control.DisplayRectangle

Tags: c#, .net, winforms

I understand the concept of Client Rectangle regarding a Form/Control,
yet I don't understand what the difference is between
`Control.ClientRectangle` and `Control.DisplayRectangle`..

After reading the MSDN pages for both of these properties, it is not clear when one of them would return a different value from the other..

The MSDN page for `.ClientRectangle` says:

> The client area of a control is the bounds of the control, minus the
>   nonclient elements, such as: Title Bar, Border, Scroll Bars, and Menu.

That's pretty clear.

Yet the MSDN page for `.DisplayRectangle` says:

> For the base control class, this is **equal to the client rectangle**.
>   However, inheriting controls might want to change this if their client
>   area differs from their display area.

That's not so clear now..
Where, in an inheriting control, would I want to make the `.DisplayRectangle` value different from the `.ClientRectangle` one?

**Control.ClientRectangle:**
https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.forms.control.clientrectangle.aspx

**Control.DisplayRectangle:**
https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.forms.control.displayrectangle.aspx

Answer (score 41, accepted):

The DisplayRectangle is the interior canvas of the control, so when you have a scrolling control, the DisplayRectangle would be larger than the ClientRectangle, which is only the area of what you see on the screen:

```
panel1.AutoScrollMinSize = new Size(0, panel1.Height * 2);
panel1.Paint += panel1_Paint;

void panel1_Paint(object sender, PaintEventArgs e) {
  e.Graphics.FillEllipse(Brushes.Red, panel1.DisplayRectangle);
  e.Graphics.DrawEllipse(Pens.Green, panel1.ClientRectangle);
}
```

[image]

Comment: Thank you very much Lars. The code piece and result screenshot are really helpful.

Answer (score 4):

LarsTech has provided a correct and sufficient answer already, but I wanted to know details about the individual sizes.
In my case I'm using a `TabControl`, which make things even more difficult, but I'll try to explain as clearly as possible.

The `TabControl` I used has 2 `TabPage`s.
There are 2 buttons on the first TabPage, placed as shown in the screenshot. The 1st button is located at the lower edge of the TabPage; the 2nd button is located underneath the first one in the not visible part of the TabPage.
The actual height of the TabPage will be greater than the height of the TabControl because of `TabPage1.AutoScroll=true`, which you can see from the scroll bar on the right edge of the TabPage. The not visible area (containing "button2") was copied into this screenshot manually and is marked with black and yellow hatch.
There are no controls on the second TabPage.

Settings are as follows:

```
TabControl.ItemSize = {65; 21}
TabPage1.Padding = {0, 0, 0, 0} 
TabPage2.Padding = {3, 3, 3, 3}
```

[image]

This configuration results in these sizes:

```
in ctor:
              TabControl:   TabPage1:     TabPage2:
Size        = {300, 120}    {292,  91}    {292,  91}
ClientSize  = {300, 120}    {292,  91}    {292,  91}
DisplaySize = {292,  91}    {292,  91}    {286,  85}
// TabPages.Size.x = TabControl.Size.x - 2 * 4;                          ("2": left+right; "4": "frame" size between TabControl and TabPage)
// TabPages.Size.y = TabControl.Size.y - 2 * 4 - TabControl.ItemSize.y;  ("2": top+bottom; "4": like above)
// TabPage1: DisplaySize == ClientSize due to Padding=0; TabPage2: DisplaySize < ClientSize due to Padding=3

in Load():
              TabControl:   TabPage1:     TabPage2:
Size        = {300, 120}    {292,  91}    {292,  91}
ClientSize  = {300, 120}    {275,  91}    {292,  91}
DisplaySize = {292,  91}    {275, 142}    {286,  85}
// TabPage1: ClientSize.x < Size.x due to ScrollBar; DisplaySize.y > ClientSize.y due to Buttons on the TabPage and AutoScroll=true

after Resize of TabControl (height +60), all elements in Tab1 directly visible now:
              TabControl:   TabPage1:     TabPage2:
Size        = {300, 180}    {292, 151}    {292,  91}
ClientSize  = {300, 180}    {292, 151}    {292,  91}
DisplaySize = {292, 151}    {292, 151}    {286,  85}
// TabPage1: ClientSize.x == Size.x because ScrollBar is not needed and therefore not shown; DisplaySize.y == ClientSize.y because all Buttons are visible also without scrolling
// NOTICE: values of Tab2 are NOT UPDATED because Tab2 is not shown; Tab1 is the selected TabPage
```

As you can see from the values, the `DisplaySize` can be bigger than the `ClientSize` if scrolling is used.

Comment: Hi Tobias. Isn't that what LarsTech wrote? "so when you have a scrolling control, the DisplayRectangle would be larger than the ClientRectangle, which is only the area of what you see on the screen:"

Comment: @spaceman: of course it's the same. It can't be different because we both answered your question, and the facts haven't changed. We just used different ways to find the answer. I wrote my answer to provide some kind of "numerical evidence" to the graphical evidence that LarsTech gave.

Comment: @Celess: See data line #6, y value ('DisplayRectangle' in Load()).

Comment: @TobiasKnauss Sorry I though you guys were talking about in general. Thought the other guy was being a bit harsh and wanted to praise you also for the real data.

Comment: Removed my original comment because it confused the issue. If could edit it would.